# Hibernate relation between two same entities

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a class A with unique ID and name. 
I would like to create a separate table which will containt two A entities and relation between them which will be added while being created. 
 
So that columns of the new table should look like this: 
First Object A(ID) | Second Object A(ID) | Relation 
where First Table Id and Second Table ID are Ids of two another objects but within the same entity.

Would u guys please give me some tips how to create it in hibernate entity? as well as proper sql script.

Comment: Do you want one to one relation b/w them or one to many?

Comment: @BhushanUniyal  Object A can have one relation with another Object A by type of Relation. For example: First object A id: 123, Second object A id: 456, Relation: money.

Comment: i am not getting clearly getting you,
suppose i have 3's A
"A id-1 | A-id 2"
"A id-1 | A-id 3"
sohere A with id-1 have relationship with A id-2 and A id-3
Is it you want?

Answer (score 0):

Machiej I am not sure about what kind of relation-ship you want 
One-to-One or One-to-many

np, you can achieve it using **@JoinTable**

Here is example of **One to Many** relation for A to A with join table;

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "a_join_a", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_a")
    ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_a"))
    private List<A> aList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<A> getaList() {
        return aList;
    }

    public void setaList(List<A> aList) {
        this.aList = aList;
    }
}
```

Here is example of **One to One** relation b/w A to A with join table (Note: this is not good idea to use join table for one to one );

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "a_join_a", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_a")
            ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_a"))
    private A childA;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public A getChildA() {
        return childA;
    }

    public void setChildA(A childA) {
        this.childA = childA;
    }

}
```

output table will same for both scenario, as you need join table:

```
mysql> desc A;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc a_join_a;
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| child_a  | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| parent_a | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```